# Multi Account deployment using github action

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, terraform, github-actions, vpc

Hi I have multiple AWS account and I am trying to run terraform script using github action but having issue with configuring the Access keys of dev and prod account.I have add the if condition to get the access key as an ENV but its not working. Below is my github action file and the error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
name: "Terraform"
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      accounts:
        description: account to use
        type: choice
        default: PROD
        options:
        - PROD
        - DEV

      #Terraform action you want to perform
      action:
        description: 'Terraform Action to Perform'
        type: choice
        options:
        - Terraform_plan
jobs:
  terraform_plan:

    name: "Terraform plan"

    if: ${{ github.event.inputs.action == 'Terraform_plan' }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Set env NEED

        id: setvars

        run: |

          if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "PROD" ]]; then

            echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.PROD_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

            echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ secrets.PROD_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

          fi



          if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "DEV" ]]; then

            echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

            echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ secrets.DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

          fi

      - name: Checkout

        uses: actions/checkout@v2



      - name: Setup Terraform

        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1



      - name: Terraform Init

        id: init

        run: terraform -chdir=vpc init        

        env:

            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:  ${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}

            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

      - name: Terraform Plan

        run: terraform -chdir=vpc plan

        env:

            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}

            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Error:

```
╷
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
│ 
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│ 
│ Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, failed to get API token, cannot get API token, operation error ec2imds: getToken, http response error StatusCode: 400, request to EC2 IMDS failed
│ 
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
│ 
╵



Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Please do not post errors as screenshots. Which AWS terraform provider version are you using?

Comment: Why not pass the Github Action secrets for AWS credentials directly to the step env for direct consumption by the TF AWS provider?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have 2 accounts so that is the main reason

Comment: @MarkoE I have updated the question and I am using terraform 1.1.9

Comment: @coder I was asking about terraform provider for AWS, not the Terraform version. :)

Comment: @MarkoE Sorry I misunderstood, it uses  hashicorp/aws v4.16.0.

Comment: What is inside of the `provider` block?

Comment: @MarkoE only aws provider, no other specs

Comment: You should also consider using [GitHub Environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) as a more streamlined method for multi-account deployments. You can use the same secret names that way logically isolated by environment and add additonal checks/reviews/etc too